# Constructor initialization list for POD member types using ()

Tags: c++, c++11

Following is a sample code I cooked up to aid my question:

```
class test {
    public:
        test(int x, int y) :  _x(x), _y() {}

    private:
        int _x, _y;
};
```

For POD (plain data types), does `_y()` (empty parenthesis) have any effect?  If so, what is _y getting initialized to?  If no effect, is it inefficient having `_y()` in the list.

Thank you,
Ahmed.

Comment: as a general rule don't use **leading underscores**, because that's a convention used by C implementations. use trailing underscores (common C++ convention), or some other convention. in most cases there's no harm done, e.g. for naming *arguments*, but it's a good idea to stay away from that which can cause harm in general, when there's no good reason to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constructor initialization lists perform direct-initialization (C++11 §12.6.2/7):

> The expression-list or braced-init-list in a mem-initializer is used to initialize the designated subobject ... according to the initialization rules of 8.5 for direct-initialization.

The initialisation rules state the `()` will value-initialize an object (§8.5/16):

> If the initializer is (), the object is value-initialized.

To value-initialize a POD type is to zero-initialize it, which means to set its value or its subobjects' values to 0 (§8.5/5):

> To value-initialize an object of type T means:
>
> - if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type (Clause 9) with a user-provided constructor (12.1), *[... not a POD]*
> - if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) non-union class type without a user-provided constructor, then the object
>     is zero-initialized and, if T’s implicitly-declared default constructor is non-trivial, *[... not a POD]*
> - if T is an array type, then each element is value-initialized;
> - otherwise, the object is zero-initialized.

In the case of an array type, it's only a POD type if its elements are POD types, so they end up being zero-initialized.

Comment: it's nice with the quotes but you forgot to provide references for those quotes. i know where they're from. the general readership probably does not (and may not even realize that they *are* quotes).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I keep forgetting about that. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The member initializer `_y()` has the effect of [value initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) and initializes `_y` to zero.